# How to create folder for target in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

Hello I have written makefile which compose lib.a from object files. I need to make .zip from this lib, create new directory for it and save. Could anybody help?

makefile:

```
CONFIG ?= BuildConfigurations/config.mk   
include $(CONFIG) 

objects = $(addsuffix /*.o, $(local_include)) 

ib.a: $(objects)  
    ${AR} -cr ${@} ${^}
```

---

config.mk:

```
local_include := Target/ASIHTTPRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of a thing is going to be platform specific to at least a degree.  If you are on linux you can just

```
ib.a: $(objects) dir
    ${AR} -cr ${@} ${^}

dir:
    mkdir dir

dir/id.zip: ib.a
    zip dir/id.zip ib.a
```

I am not sure if the commands will be the same on another platform.